# plotting the spectrum of a 256 point FFT in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have calculated a 256 point FFT of a pure sine wave of 1kHz frequency and 2V peak-to-peak amplitude.I have obtained 256 FFT coefficients and now i have to plot its spectrum.How can i plot it using matlab?.FFT coefficients are not generated using Matlab.Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you already have the FFt values you can use the second half of the fft example in matlab to show the results http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

Comment: You can use the 2D [plot function](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). For discrete values I also like to use ```stem```.

Comment: What do you mean by "FFT coefficients are not generated using Matlab"? If you include some code it will be clearer

Answer (score 1):

In order to plot the spectra from FFT coefficients, you need following information:

- Sampling frequency
- 256 FFT coefficients

First you have load the 256 coefficients into a MATLAB variable. For example, if you save the coefficient as variable `y_fft`, then the following lines of code will plot the spectra for you:

```
% plotting of spectra
p  = abs(y_fft.^2) ;
df = Fs/Npoint_fft ;
ff = 0:df:Fs/2-df ;
figure
plot (ff,p(1:end/2))
```

In above code, `Fs` is sampling frequency and `Npoint_fft` equals 256.

You can generate the signal in MATLAB and then plot spectra. Below is some code for signal generation and plotting:

```
Fs = 20000 ;
duration = 0.001 ;
t = 0: 1/Fs:duration-(1/Fs) ;
f  = 1000 ;
Npoint_fft = 256 ;

% creation and plotting of signal of 1KHz
y = sin (2 * pi * f * t) ;
plot (t,y)

% 256 point fft
y_fft = fft(y,256) ;

% plotting of spectra
p  = abs(y_fft.^2) ;
df = Fs/Npoint_fft ;
ff = 0:df:Fs/2-df ;
figure
plot (ff,p(1:end/2))
```